# CSS transition, max-height

Tags: html, css, css3, reactjs, transition

Имеется боковая [панель](https://codepen.io/bodynar/pen/qBNEGgB), содержащая в себе список с элементами разной высоты (зависит от длины текста). При сворачивании эта панель должна отображать только часть содержимого элементов списка.

Приложение описано на React.

Проблема в том, что при "разворачивании" панели - иконки резко меняют позицию без использования свойства `transition` (указано по свойству, которое изменяется). (Если менять через панель разработчика в браузере свойства, которые меняются при наличии класса - то все идет с использованием `transition`)

Не могли бы вы подсказать в чем затык\ошибка?
Это я не туда поместил `transition` (или не на то свойство) или же это косяк навешивания доп. класса для элемента?

В codepen копия работает более-менее корректно, в React-приложении же нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема никак не связана с css. Для генерации элементов я также использую уникальные идентификаторы, которые генерирую непосредственно в компоненте. При смене состояния реакт выполняет ре-рендер, в рамках которого идентификаторы заново генерируются и поддерево элементов изменяется, из-за этого `transition` не отрабатывает

```js
const mappedMenuItems: Array<SidePanelItem & { uid: string }> =
        props.items.map(menuItem => ({
            ...menuItem,
            uid: generateUid()
        }));
```